# What was your main problem, when/in performing the analysis? [dangler]

Tags: dangling-participles

> **(1)** *What was your main problem, **when** performing the analysis*?
>
> **(2)** *What was your main problem, **in** performing the analysis*?

"*When performing the analysis*" in (1) is a dangler.

"*In performing the analysis*" in (2) is not a dangler.

Am I right? Thanks!

Comment: I would argue that the comma is incorrect in both of those sentences. But punctuation aside, both sentences are fine; however, they have different meanings.

Comment: Do you mean "Is _in performing the analysis_ a noun complement, the complement of 'problem' "? Certainly, 'When performing the analysis' can be expanded to 'when you were performing the analysis' and fronted. And I'd omit the comma before _in performing_.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth, It seemes to me "_in performing the analysis_" is an adjunct but not a dangler. Do you agree? Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your definition (you should explain what *you* mean by the term), they are either both danglers, or neither of them is. (Unless of course you come up with a definition that makes it clear—but then you'd already know the answer …)

Comment: "Dangler" is not a technical term, so you can't be right in any useful sense. It's a term in some popular (and normally wrong) ideas about English syntax, but not one in use by grammarians. Normally it's used by grammar peevers and other unpleasant people.

Comment: No commas, please, but two meanings here. *When* means a problem showed up at the time of analysis, but the analysis was okay in discovering the issue (the data showed I am not popular.) *In* means a problem happened in the attempt of the analysis, so it couldn't surface any issues (I couldn't get to the data at all.)

Comment: I'd say (1) is incorrect; you have two different subjects, so you can't reduce. Compare this, where cats perform the analysis: *When performing the analysis, cats were my main problem.* You need to say *When I was performing the analysis, cats were my main problem.*